# How to prevent unwanted people from getting image of my hdd?

Tags: disk-encryption

I have done a little search about this topic but could not find anything.

Even if my hdd is removed from my computer, its contents should not be read or copied.

Comment: Encrypt the drive. Just like you tagged the question. Did you have more to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Full disk encryption

If someone has full physical access to your HDD, they can read the information stored there, there's no way to prevent that. There are various ways how this can be made harder, but ultimately they are not effective for prevention. What you can do, though, is make the raw information unusable by full disk encryption.

In essence, if accessing your data requires both the encrypted data from the HDD and a separate key that is not stored on that HDD, then gaining that HDD won't be sufficient to read your data. There are various off-shelf solutions that will do that, I'll refrain from recommending any single one.

Comment: Note that this only works against imaging when the device is powered off. If the device is powered on, anyone could image your drive remotely if they have access to your machine. Kind of an unlikely scenario depending on the speed of your connection, though.